# Why is simr constantly giving me erroneous power results in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, statistical-power

No matter what model I fit in `lmer`, it seems like `simr` never gives an accurate read of what the data is doing. For example, the effect sizes in the `iris` dataset are quite strong, so you would expect it to have higher power even with only 150 observations. However, when I run this model:

```
iris.lmer <- lmer(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + (1+Petal.Width|Species),
                  data = iris)
```

And then throw it into `simr` with 100 simulations:

```
power.iris <- powerSim(iris.lmer,
                       nsim=100)
power.iris
```

I get a power of *3.00*, which can't be possible...

```
Power for predictor 'Petal.Width', (95% confidence interval):
       3.00% ( 0.62,  8.52)

Test: unknown test
      Effect size for Petal.Width is 1.1

Based on 100 simulations, (3 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 150

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 15 s

nb: result might be an observed power calculation
```

The warnings for this run only say a few times that the model "didnt converge", but I'm not sure how that's possible when it has no problems in `lmer` and has pretty credible random/fixed effects. If I set the simulations to only 10:

```
power.iris <- powerSim(iris.lmer,
                       nsim=10)
```

I get the total opposite problem, no power at all despite an effect size of *1.1*...

```
Power for predictor 'Petal.Width', (95% confidence interval):
       0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85)

Test: unknown test
      Effect size for Petal.Width is 1.1

Based on 10 simulations, (0 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 150

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 1 s

nb: result might be an observed power calculation
```

Unlike the other times I did this with other data, this doesn't even have any warnings or errors pop up, so on the surface there is nothing wrong with my input. What is the issue here?

Comment: Why shouldn't a power of 3% not be possible?

Comment: The correlations for these measures are quite strong, the measures vary considerably between species, the pseudo r square and ICC seem to explain a ton of the variance...I'm not sure how this would work with everything basically pointing to there both being a relationship between the IV/DV and clear random effect variance by species.

Comment: My knowledge on this could be poor, so if my assessment of that is wrong then feel free to correct me.

Comment: Your current code assumes a fixed effect of `Petal.Width` of $1.1$ (that's the effect size printed in the output). The random effects structure is not tested. For what it's worth, the $p$-value for this observed effect is around $0.118$ (using the package `lmerTest`). Repeating the power simulation using Kenward-Roger tests, I get a power of $5\%$ (`power_sim <- powerSim(iris.lmer, nsim = 100, test = fixed("Petal.Width", method = "kr"), seed = 123)`). In summary, I see nothing contradictory here.

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't power typically increase as effect size increases? I would think with 150 observations and an effect size of 1.1, this would be more powerful than 3%.

Comment: All else equal, power increases with increasing effect size, yes. But the simulations don't increase anything, they just take the observed regression coefficient of 1.1. Please note, this is *not* Cohen's $d$ or anything like that, it's just the regression coefficient. Absent of some expert matter knowledge, I have no basis to say if this coefficient represents a small or large effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Power is not determined by the data alone (eg. sample size, balanced or not, etc.); it is a function of both the data and the analysis (eg. we can choose a more or less powerful test for the same hypothesis). `simr` gives an accurate read of your analysis of the `iris` data. *Note*: In my answer I consider only the model you've shown as I cannot generalize to "no matter what model I fit in `lmer`".

The issue is that you fit a random-intercept, random-slope model to three groups in a hierarchical model (groups = species). Three groups are too few to justify representing `Species` as a random sample from a population of species. One rule of thumb is that a random-effect categorical variable has at least 5 categories: [Should I treat factor xxx as fixed or random?](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random)

So `simr` appropriately advises you that there is low power to estimate the random `Species` effects.

To demonstrate I create a fake "subspecies" grouping by splitting each species into 5 subsets of equal size. The power increases as we would expect now that we have sampled 15 (instead of 3) random groups from the hypothetical population of groups.

```r
library("simr")
library("lme4")
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1234)

iris <- iris %>%
  mutate(
    Subspecies = paste0(Species, (row_number() - 1) %/% 10)
  )
iris %>%
  count(Subspecies)
#>     Subspecies  n
#> 1      setosa0 10
#> 2      setosa1 10
#> 3      setosa2 10
#> 4      setosa3 10
#> 5      setosa4 10
#> 6  versicolor5 10
#> 7  versicolor6 10
#> 8  versicolor7 10
#> 9  versicolor8 10
#> 10 versicolor9 10
#> 11 virginica10 10
#> 12 virginica11 10
#> 13 virginica12 10
#> 14 virginica13 10
#> 15 virginica14 10
```

```r
lmer.species <- lmer(
  Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + (Petal.Width | Species),
  data = iris
)
lmer.subspecies <- lmer(
  Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + (Petal.Width | Subspecies),
  data = iris
)

nsim <- 10

powerSim(lmer.species, nsim = nsim)
#> Warning in observedPowerWarning(sim): This appears to be an "observed power"
#> calculation
#> Power for predictor 'Petal.Width', (95% confidence interval):
#>        0.00% ( 0.00, 30.85)

powerSim(lmer.subspecies, nsim = nsim)
#> Warning in observedPowerWarning(sim): This appears to be an "observed power"
#> calculation
#> Power for predictor 'Petal.Width', (95% confidence interval):
#>       100.0% (69.15, 100.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. That makes much more sense now, and I recall reading before that having too few levels for random effects can be problematic. I can see now what one of the side effects of that decision can be.